# How I get the UserName, I use ASP.NET Core MVC and Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var modifiedEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.Entity is IAuditableEntity && x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified);
    ApplicationUser userLogIn = new ApplicationUser();

    foreach (var entry in modifiedEntries)
    {
        if(entry != null)
        {
            var entity = entry.Entity as IAuditableEntity;

            //in MVC5 i use HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name//In MVC6 I don't know to do

            var user = "User";
            var now = DateTime.Now;
            if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                entity.CreatedBy = user;
                entity.CreatedOn = now;
                entity.IsDeleted = false;
            }
            else
            {
                base.Entry(entity).Property(x => x.CreatedBy).IsModified = false;
                base.Entry(entity).Property(x => x.CreatedOn).IsModified = false;
                base.Entry(entity).Property(x => x.IsDeleted).IsModified = false;
            }
            entity.UpdatedBy = user;
            entity.UpdatedOn = now;
        }
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just inject an `IHttpContextAccessor` into your class (as a constructor dependency), then you can get the name from the `User` object inside the context:

```
private IHttpContextAccessor context;
public SomeRepo(IHttpContextAccessor context)
{
    this.context = context;
}

//in your method
var userName = this.context.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
```

Since you are using the identity framework, if you need additional data from the current user apart from its name, you can inject `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` and retrieve the entire `ApplicationUser` object using any of its methods like [`GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User)`](https://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/AspNetCore/Identity/UserManager-TUser/index.html#meth-Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager<TUser>.GetUserAsync)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Exactly what I needed!